# Create XML variable in SQL Server and append values to it

Tags: sql-server, xml, dynamic, cursor

Is there a way to create XML type variable in Microsoft SQL Server and append values to it using a cursor? It should work like this:

- Create empty XML type variable
- Open cursor
- Create dynamic SQL query in cursor depending on cursor value that generates result which is XML
- In each fetch append result of query to XML variable

Is this even possible?

Problem is, I am generating XML, but the query to get it is dynamic and each query gets results from another table which I get using cursor and

```
select TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

For each `table_name` I get from this cursor, there is another query which generates XML result, which should all be merged into one XML.

This is done by making query as string variable which is executed later and should append to the XML variable.

This would be sample how one of such dynamic queries could look like where later *TABLENAME* should be replaced with table_name from cursor and then execute query:

```
select
    _TABLENAME_ as 'TABLE/@path',
    (select
         t1.id as 'value/@id',
         t1.name as 'value',
         t2.name as 'value_jp'
     from 
         _TABLE_NAME t1, _TABLENAME_ + '_locale' t2
     where 
         t1.ID = t2.FK_Id and t2.FK_Locale = 38
     for xml path(''), root('rows'), type)
for xml path('')
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Have you considered that you could generate a single (large) dynamic SQL statement to answer the entire query across all of the tables and return the XML in a single select. I don't see why there'd need to be a cursor involved.